# Use earphones remote controller on Windows

Tags: windows, remote, media-player

Luckily for me, my computer recognizes presses on the Apple EarBuds' remote:

[image: GIF]

Each time the green bar goes up, it is because I pressed the middle button on the remote (The one between volume up and down)

Is there any way to have a program or Windows recognize this and control media playback as I can on an iPod?

Preferably, I'd like it to act as the keys FN-F9 to FN-F11 on my laptop, that can control iTunes, VLC, Groove Music and many other music players, instead than a program supporting a limited set of players:

[image: FN]

Comment: Pretty sure your laptop does NOT recognize the button press, but "hears" the button click as audio mic input, not a button press. You can't do anything useful with that.

Answer (score 1):

That is the recording tab of the audio dialog. What is happening here is not that your computer detects you pressing the key, but that the mic in the earbuds hears the clicking sound it makes when you press the button.

Comment: When I speak in the mic, there is no audio input. Same thing when I press on Volume Up and Down. If it was for that, I would have seen audio input for Volume Up and Down and while speaking

Comment: @charles.milette Even if you, say, clap your hands next to it?

Comment: yes, even if I clap my hands next to it

Comment: If it is your headphone controller sending it down the mic line, you cant use it due to windows recognizing it as what it is - a mic signal. Perhaps other software, but [product recommendations are off-topic here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).